# Passing Parameters - Dynamic HTML with JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a javascript function that dynamically builds a table. I have a function that gets called once a button inside of that table is clicked.

```
var bankButtonRefresh = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="refreshBankDataFunction('+parentId+')" 
class="btn-sm btn-primary permissionDeny pull-right" role="button">Refresh</a>';
row +='<td style="position:relative">' + bankButtonRefresh2 + '</td>';
```

When I printed out the value of bankButtonRefresh2 the value is:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="refreshBankDataFunction(a34c0000000jiecccA)" 
class="btn-sm btn-primary permissionDeny pull-right" role="button">Refresh</a>
```

So I can see that the parentId is passing incorrectly.

I am not trying to do anything fancy, I am just trying to get the `Id` passed to the function but I am getting no response from the button when I click on it.

```
function refreshBankDataFunction(obj){ //obj is the parentId
      alert('got into the function: ' + obj);
}
```

Am I not passing the parentId correctly?

Comment: There is no type that matches `a34c0000000jiecccA`.  Did you mean to wrap that in quotes?

Comment: I thought it would pick it up as a type- ID

Comment: @Olivia, Joseph means it will work if you do this: refreshBankDataFunction('a34c0000000jiecccA')

Comment: If you leave it  without quotes, JS will think it's a variable and not an actual value

Comment: I see. the only issue with that is the HTML reads the parentId as a string if I do that: `onchange="refreshBankDataFunction('+ ''' + parentId + ''' +')"`

Comment: What is `parentId` then a value or an object, or an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var bankButtonRefresh = '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="refreshBankDataFunction({param:'+parentId+'})" class="btn-sm btn-primary permissionDeny pull-right" role="button">Refresh</a>';


function refreshBankDataFunction(obj){ //obj is the parentId
      alert('got into the function: ' + obj.data.param);
}
```

Comment: thank you, I updated my action from onChange to onClick and this fix worked!

Comment: I am glad you got it working:) Please accept an answer in order to close the question.

Answer (score 0):

Where you are building your link add an extra set of wrapping single quotes such as: `onClick="refreshBankDataFunction(''+parentId+'')"`